# "Contains" and "Not Contains" methods in SQL or by using Java script UDF

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can we use "Contains" and "NotContains" methods in SQL i.e., How do I check if a string or a column value is contained in another column of a table.

Problem Statement:

1. How do I check if a string "ABC" is contained/Not contained in "Column1"
2. How do I check if a "Column1" value is contained/Not contained in "Column2"

If not SQL can we use JavaScript UDF or any other means to make this happen?

Comment: Look up the NOT clause and LIKE clause in SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL SELECT WHERE field contains words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290857/sql-select-where-field-contains-words)

Comment: I am looking for a function which can be used in a case statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6740134

Comment: Why do you want to use a function when a simple SQL command solves the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CONTAINS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/contains.html):

> Returns true if expr1 contains expr2. Both expressions must be text or binary expressions.
>
> ```
> CONTAINS( <expr1> , <expr2> )
> ```

---

Examples:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE (Colum1, 'ABC');
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE NOT (Colum1, 'ABC');

SELECT * FROM tab WHERE (Colum1, Column2);
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE NOT (Colum1, Column2);
```

---

It is worth mentioning Snowflake LIKE/[ILIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ilike.html) [[ANY]](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like_any.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE Column1 LIKE ANY ('%ABC%','%XYZ%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Like` operator I believe i am not sure what exactly are you looking for but here is an example below. For more details: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

```
select column
from [table]
where column Like %ABC%
```

or if you already know the values that you are looking for in a specific column then you can use `in` operator:

```
select column from [table] where column in ('ABC','XYZ')
```

This will give you the rows for the column, where the values are equal to either ABC or XYZ